# Line chart with confidence intervals in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am amazed that I struggle to find a PowerBI visualisation that allows me to plot a line with confidence intervals:

i.e. something as simple as:

[image]

My data looks like:

[image]

Is there really nothing out there that allows CI to be plotted as shaded areas around a line, e.g. using three inputs (line = y, shaded area =  lower + upper)?

PS. I'm an R user who is trying to replicate simple things in PowerBI

Comment: The standard set of visuals are limited, it may have to be a custom one, However have you tried using the R visual if you can do it in R? Then format to look like a Power Visual

Comment: I'll have a look. I was under the (false?) impression that the R visuals are static... and I'd like the hover-over-effect to reveal underlying number

Comment: The visuals are static sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does not offer the same chart configuration level that you have in R.  There are no charts that support configurable confidence levels currently available.

Possible work arounds are to create a custom visual or R based chart, but that detracts a little from the benefit of moving over to a Power BI as a pre built visualisation tool

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, whilst it is very easy to plot the current values and the time-series forecast using a Line chart visual, it is impossible to add the prediction interval to this plot using standard tools.

That's why I decided to develop a Power BI Time-series Custom Visual that fills the gap. Here an example:

[image]

You can find the GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/lucazav/power-bi-time-series-custom-visual).

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking online for a way to do this, and have found no good answer. For now my solution is to use error bars in the shape of a shaded area. First you need to enable them in `File > Options and settings > Options > Preview features > Error bars`. Then under Visualizations tab navigate to Analytics, and select Error bars. Enable the feature, select Upper Bound, and Lower Bound data, enable Shade area, and you are done. Additionally you can enable Line, and Tooltip options. Below is an example with the data you provided in your question.

[Example confidence intervals.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSTji.png)

PS: This was done in PBI Desktop version 2.105.664.0.